# What is the best approach to find a system's domain name?

Tags: linux, hostname, domain

I use the following syntax in order to find the domain name on a Linux machine:

```
hostname | sed s'/\./ /g' | awk '{print $2}'

hostname
master02.sys65.com

hostname | sed s'/\./ /g' | awk '{print $2}'
sys65
```

but I think this approach is not very elegant.

I would like to see other ways to find the domain name (***without* the final `.com`**).

Comment: Do you need portability? Because random GNU flags are a great way to set the hostname to `-d` on Solaris.

Comment: @thrig in this case it’s not a GNU flag, but I get your point. Presumably if you don’t run it as root it won’t have that side-effect, will it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
hostname -d
```

for this.

To drop the last part of the domain, there any many different techniques; for example

```
hostname -d | sed -E 's/\.[^.]+$//'
```